# Background tasks in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to run a robocopy command in powershell in the background while the script proceeds with other tasks.

So for example, the script would start copying and rather than wait for the robocopy to finish, it moves on with the next lines of script. How is something like this best accomplished?

Thank you!

Comment: start-job, runspaces, `&` (& works only in powershell 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start-job should do your job. Use like this:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {& robocopy /?}
```

Then you can check the job by using `Get-job` and finally if you want to receive  the job output then you can use

```
Receive-job Job1 ##Job1 being the job name.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @DominicBrunetti: Happy to help you mate. Enjoy PS Coding